# How to create text file and write data into it using TASM

Tags: file, assembly, x86-16, tasm, dosbox

I have to write a program in assembly (using TASM for compiling) which will create a text file and write data into it.
It should be something like a log file that would contain information about user activities.

Below is the code of a small sample program to give you a better understanding of what I mean.
Once the program ran, it should create a text file and write there a message "Program began its work".
If the user pressed "1" it would write a message "User pressed 1" into a text file.
If the user presses "2" it would write "User pressed 2" into a text file.
If the user presses "3" it would write "Program finished its work" into a text file.
Each message in the text file should start from a new line.

```
.model small

.data

msg_start db "Press 1 or 2",0dh, 0ah,"Press 3 to exit the program$"

msg_1 db "You pressed 1" ,0dh, 0ah,"Press any key to continue$"
msg_2 db "You pressed 2" ,0dh, 0ah,"Press any key to continue$"

.code
.startup


start:

        ;Clearing screen
        MOV AH, 0 
        MOV AL, 2 
        INT 10H 
        
        ;Start message output
        mov ax, seg msg_start
        mov ds, ax
        mov dx, offset msg_start
        mov ah, 9h
        int 21h
        
        ;Ask user to press the key
        mov ah, 1h
        int 21h
                
        ;Comparing pressed key
        cmp al, 31h ;Pressed "1"
        je label_1  ;Jump to "label_1"
        cmp al, 32h ;Pressed "2"
        je label_2  ;Jump to "label_2"
        cmp al, 33h ;Pressed "3"
        je label_3  ;Jump to "label_3"
        
        jmp start ;Pressed any other key
   

label_1:

        ;Clearing screen
        MOV AH, 0 
        MOV AL, 2 
        INT 10H 
        
        ;Message output
        mov ax, seg msg_1
        mov ds, ax
        mov dx, offset msg_1
        mov ah, 9h
        int 21h
        
        ;Ask user to press the key
        mov ah, 1h
        int 21h

        cmp al, 33h ;Pressed "3"
        je label_3  ;Jump to "label_3"

        jmp start ;Jumping to start label


label_2:


        ;Clearing screen
        MOV AH, 0 
        MOV AL, 2 
        INT 10H 
        
        ;Message output
        mov ax, seg msg_2
        mov ds, ax
        mov dx, offset msg_2
        mov ah, 9h
        int 21h
        
        ;Ask user to press the key
        mov ah, 1h
        int 21h

        cmp al, 33h ;Pressed "3"
        je label_3  ;Jump to "label_3"

        jmp start ;Jumping to start label

label_3:

        ;Exit the program
        mov ah, 4ch
        mov al, 01
        int 21h

end
```

Comment: And what is the question? Consult an [`int 21h` reference](http://spike.scu.edu.au/~barry/interrupts.html) to see which file I/O-related interrupt functions are available to you in DOS.

Answer (score 2):

When you want to work with files, you'll need to employ some services of operating system. DOS functions are served by [INT 21h](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/int-21.htm). Look for functions with FILE in their name (forget the obsolete FCB file functions).

Manipulation with disk files requires *file handle*, which is an identifier of internal object established by OS when the file is created. Handle can be obtained from DOS with function [CREATE FILE](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-2778.htm)

```
.data
FileName DB "Rimanio.log",0
.text
   MOV AH,3Ch  ; Function CREATE OR TRUNCATE FILE.
   SUB CX,CX   ; 0=Normal file attributes.
   MOV DX, OFFSET FileName ; Offset of file name.
   INT 21h     ; Invoke DOS function. 
   JC Error    ; Go to report if error occured.
   MOV BX,AX   ; Save the handle to BX.
```

With the handle of just created file it's easy to write a string to it, using [WRITE](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-2791.htm). Write should be terminated with [CLOSE FILE](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-2782.htm), this will flush the written contents to the file and update its size, time and other attributes. You can then check it in console window with `type Rimanio.log`.

Comment: "Write should be terminated with [CLOSE FILE](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-2782.htm)". I find this a bit mis-leading. It looks like every single WRITE should be followed by CLOSE. Perhaps rephrase as "When all WRITEs to your file have finished, you need to CLOSE the file"

Comment: @SepRoland Generally, yes, for the best performace it's better to not close and reopen the file very often.  However, OP wants a *log file* of user activities, and the log cannot be investigated on runtime (in other console window) when it's not closed after each activity.